# Authorisation Attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, custom-attributes

I have a WPF application from a client that I need to add a IsInRoleAtrribute to for certain methods in a class.

So I created my IsInRole class like this, as a test;

```
namespace CustomAttributeSample
{
    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class IsInRoleAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Role { get; set; }

        public IsInRoleAttribute()
        {
            //open the xml file
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load("Data.xml");
        }

        public override bool Match(object obj)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override bool Equals (object obj)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I decorate my method like this, again as a test so far;

```
    [IsInRole(Role="Admin")]
    private bool Save()
    {
```

However I cannot prevent the method from being executed.

I can do this in MVC no probs but this is my first WPF application in a number of years so I know I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not very familiar with that either but try to put this instead:

```
[AuthorizationAttribute(AuthorizationType.Allow, "Admin")]
```

this should work if you are using the MVVM paradigm ;-)

source:  [WPF Command and claim/role based security](http://marcelwouters.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/wpf-command-and-claimrole-based-security/)

Comment: Thanks.  Will implement tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: Downloaded the demo code and it works. Now to figure out how to use it in my application.  :)